# there is a type error in my react typescript project middleware

Tags: reactjs, typescript, object, middleware, react-typescript

This is a project that i am working on in react typescript. i have created this middleware where i am converting all the coming data from backend to change the object keys into camelCase and changing the object keys case that i am sending back to snakeCase. Now for changing the case i am using a package https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-convert-case. Now this is the code of my middleware

```
import Axios from 'axios'
import * as queryString from 'query-string'
import * as jsConvert from 'js-convert-case'
import { cleanParams } from '_utilities/common'
import { REQUEST_TYPES } from './constants'
import { useLoginUser } from '_store/user'

interface IAuth {
  method?: string
  url?: string
  data?: any
  params?: any
  contentType?: string
  isTransformRequestRequired?: boolean
  isAuthroizedToken?: boolean
}

export function apiCaller({
  method = REQUEST_TYPES.GET,
  url = '',
  params = {},
  data = {},
  contentType = 'application/json',
  isAuthroizedToken = true,
  isTransformRequestRequired = true,
}: IAuth) {
  const user = useLoginUser.getState().user
  const setLogout = useLoginUser.getState().setLogout
  const token = user?.data?.token || ''

  let headers
  if (isAuthroizedToken) {
    headers = {
      Authorization: `Token ${token}`,
      'Content-Type': contentType,
    }
  } else {
    headers = {
      'Content-Type': contentType,
    }
  }

  return Axios({
    method,
    url,
    params,
    paramsSerializer: (queryParams) =>
      queryString.stringify(jsConvert.snakeKeys(cleanParams(queryParams))),
    data,
    transformRequest: [
      (reqData) =>
        isTransformRequestRequired ? JSON.stringify(jsConvert.toSnakeCase(reqData)) : reqData,
    ],
    transformResponse: [
      (respData) => {
        if (typeof respData === 'string')
          return jsConvert.camelKeys(JSON.parse(respData), {
            recursive: true,
            recursiveInArray: true,
          })
        else {
          return jsConvert.camelKeys(respData, { recursive: true, recursiveInArray: true })
        }
      },
    ],
    headers: headers,
    responseType: 'json',
    validateStatus: (status) => status >= 200 && status < 300,
  })
    .then(({ data: resp }) => resp)
    .catch((error) => {
      if (error?.response?.status === 401) {
        setLogout()
      } else {
        throw error
      }
    })
}
```

now everything else is working fine but i am getting a typo in this area

```
paramsSerializer: (queryParams) =>
          queryString.stringify(jsConvert.snakeKeys(cleanParams(queryParams))),
```

and it is saying

```
Argument of type 'object | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Record<string, any>'.
  Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'Record<string, any>'.ts(2345)
(alias) snakeKeys(obj: any, opt?: Options | undefined): object | null
export snakeKeys
```

my cleanParams function is as follows:

```
export const cleanParams = (obj: Record<string, any>): Record<string, any> => {
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    if (obj[key] === false) {
      delete obj[key]
    } else if (obj[key]) {
      if (key === 'isDisabled') {
        delete obj[key]
        obj.enabled = false
      }
    }
  })
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    if (
      obj[key] === null ||
      obj[key] === '' ||
      obj[key] === undefined ||
      obj[key].length === 0 ||
      (key === 'status' && obj[key] === 0)
    ) {
      delete obj[key]
    }
  })
  Object.keys(obj).forEach((key) => {
    if (obj[key] === true) {
      obj[key] = 1
    }
  })
  return obj
}
```

now i am specifying cleanParams's return type to be an object. but the typo is still there.
I have also tried to modify the paramsserializer part to check and only proceed if the cleanParams is returning the object but i am still getting the same typescript warning.